# Ajax form data php POST not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm working on this page: http://sitesdemo.mghospedagem.com/ivam-entregas/3/33209.html

And I'm facing a problem:

It uses SMTP to send data to an Email, but the only data that is being sent is from the fields "Nome" and "Email". The other fields "Endereço de Partida", "Endereço de Chegada" and "Detalhes do Serviço" are simply empty on submission.

Which php code is:

```
    <?php
/*
 * Vinteum Desenvolvimento
 * tiago@vinteum.com 
 */

require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php');

$nome  = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$msg   = $_POST['txtDetalhes'];

$end1 =  $_POST['1'];
$end2 =  $_POST['txtEnderecoChegada'];




try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

        $body .= "<h2>Pedido de orçamento para entrega</h2>";       
        $body .= "Nome: $nome <br>";       
        $body .= "E-mail: $email  <br>";        
        $body .= "<br>";
        $body .= "Mensagem: <br> $msg"; 

        $body .= $msg;
        $body .= "<br>";
        $body .= "Endereço de partida: $end1 <br>";
        $body .= "Endereço de chegada: $end2 <br>"; 

        $body .= "<br>";
        $body .= "----------------------------";
        $body .= "<br>";
        $body .= "Enviado em <b>".date("h:m:i d/m/Y")." por ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."</b>"; //Mostra data e Endereço IP
        $body .= "<br>";
        $body .= "----------------------------";

    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP server port, geralmente porta 25 ou 587
    $mail->Host       = "mail.xxxxxxx.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "test@xxxxxxxx.com";     // SMTP server username
    $mail->Password   = "xxxxxxxxx";            // SMTP server password

    //$mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $nome); //Responder para

    $mail->From       = $email; //De E-mail
    $mail->FromName   = $nome;  //De Nome

    $to = "myemail@hotmail.com"; //Para

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject  = "Orçamento para entrega"; //Assunto

    $mail->AltBody    = "Para ver essa mensagem utilize um cliente com suporte HTML!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso.<br><a href="33209.html">VOLTAR</a><br />';

    echo $end1;

     //retorno (html) devolvido para o ajax caso sucesso
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //retorno devolvido para o ajax caso erro
}

?>
```

Here is the HTML and Javascript code:

http://jsbin.com/qudumegihu/1/edit

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending your data with:

```
var urlData = "&nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&msg=" + msg + "&end1=" + end1 + "&end2=" + end2;
```

and then trying to grab `txtDetalhes`and `txtEnderecoChegada`from `$_POST`, that doesn't exist. You should be using `$_POST['end1']` and `$_POST['end2]` instead.

**A little tip**: try using `var_dump($_POST);` to see its contents. it's really helpful.

Comment: How exactly can I replace `var urlData = "&nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&msg=" + msg + "&end1=" + end1 + "&end2=" + end2;
`
Then?
Cause it's working now with that code.

Answer (score 0):

try this one. in your sendmailivam.php . Try to look Ravan's answer.

```
   <?php
/*
 * Vinteum Desenvolvimento
 * tiago@vinteum.com 
 */

require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php');

$nome  = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg   = $_POST['msg'];
$end1 =  $_POST['end1'];
$end2 =  $_POST['end2'];
```

Comment: The ids are not end1 and end2.

Comment: do you still have any problem?

Comment: With the script, not. But I do have a problem with Ravan's answer, it got me worried, can you check out the discussion?